# Receiving JSON POST requests from HPKP error respondents

Tags: json, uri

I'm experimenting with setting up HPKP (https://scotthelme.co.uk/hpkp-http-public-key-pinning/) on my web server and one of its options is to specify an error reporting URI in the header for clients to send error notices to in the form of a JSON POST request structured as such:

{
     "date-time": date-time,
     "hostname": hostname,
     "port": port,
     "effective-expiration-date": expiration-date,
     "include-subdomains": include-subdomains,
     "noted-hostname": noted-hostname,
     "served-certificate-chain": [
       pem1, ... pemN
     ],
     "validated-certificate-chain": [
       pem1, ... pemN
     ],
     "known-pins": [
       known-pin1, ... known-pinN
     ]
}

My question is how can I set something up within Linux to listen for the JSON POSTs on port 80 (or 443)?

Does anything exist for this already? thanks everyone for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Scott Helme, who's link you included, also runs this service which takes care of it for you:

https://report-uri.io

Alternatively if you want to try it out yourself any web scripting language (cgi via perl, php... etc.) should be able to listen to a post request and dump it out to a log file. Personally I use a NodeJS service, but anything will do. I'm not aware of any scripts people have shared but that's probably because there no need as so simple (listen for post request, print out results).

Also you cannot listen on port 443 on the same domain as the site you are monitoring as the report also uses HPKP so won't be able to connect, since the only time you want to report is when you can't connect! Would work fine in report only mode though.

I know you're only experimenting but I would caution to **be very careful** with HPKP as its very easy to brick your site with this, and it adds a lot of extra considerations to certificate renewal. Personally I don't think it's that great as the risk it introduces, to me anyway, far out weigh the risk it mitigates for most sites. More thoughts of that from me here: https://www.tunetheweb.com/security/http-security-headers/hpkp/#downsides